# Tracking down references to a service

Tags: asp.net

I get this error in my ASP.NET 3.5 website:

Error   3   Cannot update project reference 'Services'. Source project not available.

How can I track down any reference to this assembly so I can then delete it? It must be called from somewhere. I no longer have an assembly in my project with this name.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check your references: in your Reference Paths Dialog Box (Visual Basic) or the Reference Paths Page, Project Designer (C#, J#).

See this link in MSDN for details: [How to: Add or Remove References in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have much luck with the previous answer for web projects, so I thought I'd offer another way. Web project references are kept (non-intuitively) in the solution file, and with care you can edit this file to remove the reference.

- Close the solution if you have it open, then open solution file in a text editor.
- Search for name of the project that failed to load. This should bring you to the configuration section for your web project.
- Inside that should be a line beginning with "ProjectReferences", with a semicolon-separated list of projects.
- If you CAREFULLY remove the offending project, which includes a GUID and the assembly name for the project, then save the solution file, you should be good to go.
- Be sure to allow yourself a backup strategy in case something goes wrong.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008; I don't know if it works exactly the same way in other versions.